# Flask jobs working outside application context

Tags: python, flask, redis, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to access Flask application context to use `db.session` which let me update my database.
As I want to create jobs in a redis worker, I need to make the worker to know the application context to update my database.

```
--> app
--> routes
   --> routes.py
--> jobs.py
--> __init__.py
config.py
```

I am using Flask blueprint. To access app context in my `jobs.py` file I created a bluprint for this file.

The thing is that when I am trying to use `db.session.query(...)` I get the following error:

*RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.*

However, I am using the `app_context` in my `jobs.py` and I have the same error.

```py
with current_app.app_context():
    test = dbmodel.query.filter_by(...)
    print(test)
```

Note that I need rq jobs are working perfectly if I do not need to update my database.